# How do you populate a dropdownlist using XSLT

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt

I am able to create a downdownlist. However, i am not able to populate anything into it with XML data. Can anyone help me out on this? Thanks!

This is the XML code

```
<group name="Security / PDPA">
  <section name="Control" db_field_name="control_score">
    <field is_admin_field="N" required="Y">
      <question_title>Verify customer's details when necessary</question_title>
      <type>List</type>
      <db_field_name>verify_customers_details_when_necessary_control</db_field_name>
      <options>
        <item score="2">Yes</item>
        <item score="0">No</item>
        <item score="2">No with reason</item>
      </options>
      <db_field_length>14</db_field_length>
      <additional_comment/>
    </field></section></group>
```

This is the XSLT code

```
 <select name="form">
      <xsl:for-each select="form/fieldset/group/section/field/options">
        <option>
          <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:value-of select="item"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </option>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have not shown a full XML, because your Xpath expression in the `xsl:for-each` is looking for `form/fieldset/group/section/field/options`, but neither the initial `form` or `fieldset` are shown in your XML.

With that in mind, the issue is probably because you are selecting the `options` element with the `xsl:for-each`, but there is only one of those. You should be selecting `item` elements, because it looks like you want to output an `<option>` tag for each item

```
  <xsl:for-each select="form/fieldset/group/section/field/options/item">
    <option>
      <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="@score"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </option>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Or better still, use Attribute Value Templates to shorten the code

```
  <xsl:for-each select="form/fieldset/group/section/field/options/item">
    <option value="{@score}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </option>
  </xsl:for-each>
```